# Getting data from quote items collection issue in M1

Tags: magento-1, collection, quoteitem

This is my collection:

```
$collection = 

Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getItemsCollection()
                    ->addFieldToFilter('product_type', ['eq' => 'bundle']);
$collection->getSelect()
      ->joinLeft(
            ['sfqio' => 'sales_flat_quote_item_option'],
            'main_table.item_id = sfqio.item_id'
      )->where('code = ?', 'additional_options');
//$collection->getSelect()->columns('sfqio.value');
```

I want to get the data from the `value` column, but it is null:

```
foreach ($collection as $items => $item){
     var_dump($item->getData('value'));
}
```

If I display the query and executed directly in phpmyadmin(for instance) , I got the `value` column with a serialized data.  In my `var_dump` case , it is always null. Why ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's probably something related to the code in your project as the following code works for me:

```
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();

$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load(1)->getItemsCollection();
$collection->getSelect()
    ->joinLeft(
        ['sfqio' => 'sales_flat_quote_item_option'],
        'main_table.item_id = sfqio.item_id'
    );

foreach ($collection as $items => $item){
     var_dump($item->getData('value'));
}
```